# how to create wallet for tokens

Tags: ether, wallets

trying to find out but still didnt got how all this work ? How to create a wallet for the token you created on ERC20 contract ? what all things need to know and the flow of over all process can anyone ?

Answer (score 1):

Any Ethereum wallet address can hold any ERC20 token because the contract simply maps your address to an integer balance. Therefore, you can use the same wallet you already use for Ether.

Comment: so basically you are saying that the ethereum address is used to transfer ERC20 tokens ? Is it possible to create another wallet other then the one we use for Ethereum and if the same address will use then how the address will specify which one is ethereum and which one is the token created ?

Comment: also how to create a wallet for the tokens made in ERC20 ?

Comment: @macrichard your follow up question does not make any sense

Comment: @macrichard I suggest doing a bit more research into how ERC20 tokens work. ERC20 is just a special type of smart contract, which you call using a standard Ethereum wallet address. You can create as many Ethereum wallets as you want. Any of them can "hold" your ERC20 token, and any of them can hold ETH.